# Laravel Architecture, several similar models to be combined?

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

I have a laravel app with products which can be associated to quotes.

The problem i have is that a quote is almost the same as an order

So when a quote is accepted i dump all the values from quote to order and re-associate all of the items to the order instead of quote.

I planned to make a type field on orders and just change type from quote to order but doing that makes it hard to run eloquent queries on product relationships such as..

To determine if product is sold: Products::has('order');

What is the correct way to implement this design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by applying additional constraints on the relationship.

```
class Product extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the orders for the product.
     */
    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Order')->where('type', '=', 'order');
    }

    /**
     * Get the quotes for the product.
     */
    public function quotes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Order')->where('type', '=', 'quote');
    }
}
```

Now you can check quotes and orders for a product using the following code

```
Product::has('quotes');
Product::has('orders');
```

If you don't want to write additional constraints in the relation method and only `orders()` relation is added, then you can use the `whereHas()` method when needed.

```
$orders = Product::whereHas('orders', function (Builder $query) {
    $query->where('type', '=', 'order');
})->get();


$orders = Product::whereHas('orders', function (Builder $query) {
    $query->where('type', '=', 'quote');
})->get();
```

Comment: Exactly what was needed! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep both, order and quotes, you could create multiple N-N relations or a single N-N polymorphic releation

```
product 1-N quote N-1 order_data
product 1-N order N-1 order_data
```

Order_data contains all information about the order. The quote and order table defining the kind of order.

If you plan to also introduce other kinds of customer requests, like  credit notes and other additional. You should think about creating a polymorphic relationship.

```
Product 1-N order_type N-N order_data
```

- Product: contains product information
- Order_data: represents different customer inputs
- Order_type: different order relationships

You can create order data with multiple releations. So a orderType  quote, order and credit can exists at the same time, which is important for documentation.